Cannot Setup Microsoft Azure AI Video Indexer ARM Account on Microsoft Azure AI Video Indexer Web Portal
I’ve set up a new resource group for Microsoft Azure AI Video Indexer with the service and StorageV2 successfully. I used the same account for both Azure and Azure AI Video Indexer, it is a personal Microsoft account. However, when I open the Video Indexer Web Portal, I still see a TRIAL badge.
When I click Create Unlimited Account under the profile section, it navigates me to creating a new resource in the Azure Portal.
How can I merge my existing Microsoft Azure AI Video Indexer resource group with the Microsoft Azure AI Video Indexer Web Portal?
Thanks.

I faced the same issue and solved it by switching to the correct directory.
You can do this by clicking the profile button in the top-right corner and selecting 'Switch directory.' After switching directories, you will still need to switch accounts by clicking the 'Accounts' tab, which is located between the 'Create Unlimited Account' button and the notification button.
However, I still face a login issue on the API portal, where it says the same email has been used for two or more users.
